# SDKMAN not showing previously installed java

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, sdkman

In my ubuntu 18.04 I have preinstalled oracle java 8 and adoptium java 17. After installing SDKMAN when I try to find existing java, it shows no version is installed.

```
$ sdk current java

Not using any version of java
```

SDKMAN version is `SDKMAN 5.16.0`

How do I link already installed java to the SDKMAN so that I can switch between java versions using it? Or do I have to install java again using SDKMAN?